# How to change SP people picker label with javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, people-picker

How do you change the label (not field values) of a SharePoint people picker using javascript?

Having a foggy moment where nothing seems to be working.

Comment: The label? Column name? Or the help text for the control?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean about the label of the people picker?

If you want to change the column name, we can go to list settings to change it.

If you want to change the help text of the people picker, we can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("span.sp-peoplepicker-initialHelpText").text("Enter user information..");
});
</script>
```

[image]